# How to implement Upcoming Date Countdown in flutter

Tags: flutter, countdowntimer

I have a task to implement upcoming event date countdown. Example 1 months 2 days remaining. date is received from api like this 2021-10-18 17:00:00.000Z. I tried some examples but didn't got required output. Below is my implemented code

```
static String? dateDiff(String date){

    if(date != "null") {
  
      final date1 = DateTime.now().toUtc();
      final DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse(date).toUtc();

      final difference = date2.difference(date1).inDays;

      print(difference); //
      return difference.toString(); //
    }
  }
```

Comment: Share sample you tried and Do you want to convert `2021-10-18 17:00:00.000Z` to 17Months 22 days from current date ?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Countdown Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451276/date-countdown-timer)

Comment: 2021-10-18 17:00:00.000Z is getting from api. So for this date it should show 1 month 2 days remaining something like that.

Comment: @Arul I have updated question with my implemented code

Answer (score -1):

You can check the answer here out

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64451276/date-countdown-timer)

Comment: Do not only use links, add information and tell what you know to fix the problem. if you want to only add links drop it in comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).